# Unsupported operand types in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a calculation form in Laravel Scheduler that works perfectly. Now I have copied the same code to *inside* "Controller," but it doesn't work, giving the error message: "Unsupported operand types."

Code:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $request['url_getmasternodecount']);

        $response->getStatusCode();
        $result = $response->getBody();
        $getmasternodecount = json_decode($result, true);

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $request['url_getdifficulty']);

        $response->getStatusCode();
        $result = $response->getBody();
        $getdifficulty = json_decode($result, true);
        $blockreward =  2222222/$getdifficulty+2600/9^2;

        $chain_second = 86400/$request['chain_second'];

        $mnreward = $request['mnreward']/100;

        $roi = 1/$getmasternodecount*$blockreward*$mnreward*$chain_second*365/1000;
```

On the last line, Laravel say there is some error. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely trying to perform mathematical operations on an array.

This code here stands out:

```
$getdifficulty = json_decode($result, true);
$blockreward =  2222222/$getdifficulty+2600/9^2;
```

At this point, `$getdifficulty` is an array, and you are trying to use it to divide 2222222 and then add figures to it.

You are doing the same thing with `$getmasternodecount`.